# Regular expression to extract content between []

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I have an expression:

```
[training_width]:lofmimics
```

I want to extract the content between the [], in the above example I want

```
training_width
```

I've tried the following:

```
QRegularExpression regex("\[(.*?)\]");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(strProcessed);
QString textYouWant = match.captured(1);
```

Where `strProcessed` contains the original text, but so far it didn't work.

Comment: Note the backslashes must be doubled. Try negated character class: `\\[([^\\]\\[]*)\\]`. Or set `regex.setMinimal(true)` and use `regex("\\[(.*)\\]")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your regex is that backslashes must be doubled.

So, there are 2 solutions:

- Use the pattern with `.*?` doubling the backslashes (`"\\[(.*?)\\]"`)

Sample:

```
QRegularExpression regex("\\[(.*?)\\]");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(strProcessed);
QString textYouWant = match.captured(1);
```

- Use a negated character class `[^\\]\\[]*` that matches 0+ characters other than `[` and `]`:

Sample:

```
QRegularExpression regex("\\[([^\\]\\[]*)\\]");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(strProcessed);
QString textYouWant = match.captured(1);
```

The difference between them is that the first - since `QRegularExpression` implements Perl-like regexps - won't match newlines (as `.` in Perl-like regexps does not match a newline by default, you'd need to specify `QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption` flag). The second one, since it is using a negated character class, will match anything, even newlines, between `[` and the next closest `]`.

Comment: QRegularExpression supports lazy quantifiers (QRegExp doesn't).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: True, I found the [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#minimal-matching). The answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this pattern:

```
\\[([^\\]]*)
```

So `$1` is containing expected result.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD0zP3/2)